# Is there a NSURLError enum-like constant for code -6003?

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, nserror

When I receive a `401` response from the server, the error code is `-6003`. I need to catch that and do something. Instead of

```
switch error.code {
  case -6003:
  // TODO:
}
```

I'd like it to be more

```
switch error.code {
  case NSURLError...:
  // TODO:
}
```

I tried searching, looked through the `NSURLError` file, went through the 'exhaustive' list on [NSHipsters](http://nshipster.com/nserror/) and came out empty. Is there one and where can I find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

rather than switching on the error code why dont you just switch on the HTTP response code?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.co.uk")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard (error == nil) else {
        print("ERROR: error occured in request: \(request) \(error)")
        return
    }

    if let statusCode = (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {

        switch(statusCode) {
        case 200...299:
             print("should be good")
        case 400:
             print("bad request")
        default:
             print("Unknown status code received: \(statusCode)")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What are the `break` commands for in your `switch` statement?